# Why can't I access wix's My Collection from my backend code?

Tags: velo

[image: Here is the wix database and I need access to Admin collection]

Because I add them from the dashboard and fetch them into my flutter app with api
this is my api code:

```
       export async function get_adminData(request) {

          let options = {
             "headers": {
             "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
         }
         };
      try {
         const results = await wixData.query("Admin")
        .eq("url", "specificValue")
        .eq("image", "specificValue")
        .eq("text", "specificValue")
        .eq("article", "specificValue")
        .find();

    if (results.items.length > 0) {
        options.body = results.items;
        return ok(options);
    } else {
        return notFound({});
    }
    } catch (error) {
    options.body = {
        "error": error
    };
    return serverError(options);
   }
         }
```

But I can only access collects that are under Wix App Collection.
I am new to wix and flutter so please help.

Answer (score 1):

First and most obvious issue here is usually permissions issue

Try to check everything with this article
https://support.wix.com/en/article/velo-exposing-a-site-api-with-http-functions

> Permissions HTTP functions, no matter how they are invoked, always run
> with the permissions of an anonymous site visitor.